# Incorrect result of the function with recursion

Tags: python, recursion, tree

This function returns correct number of the tree depths, but incorrect paths.

```
all_paths = []
all_plen = []

def calc_path(case_list, curPath, d):

d_list = [cl for cl in case_list if (type(cl) == list)]     # Search in depth

if not d_list:                          # +1 path
    all_paths.append(curPath)
    all_plen.append(d)

for cl in d_list:
    cPath = curPath
    cPath.append(case_list.index(cl))
    calc_path(cl, cPath, d + 1)

def main():
    c_list = [('A0', 4), ('B0', 5), ('C0', None), 
                                   [('A1', 1), ('B1', None), 
                                              [('A2', 13), ('B2', 32)], 
                                    ('C1', 15)
                                   ], 
          ('D0', 23), ('E0', None), [('A11', 7)]]
    calc_path(c_list, [], 0)
    print all_plen
    print all_paths

if __name__=='__main__':
    main()
```

How can I return path avoiding global variable?

UPDATED.

I'm trying to get all paths in a tree.
I had been trying to pass 'all_paths' as argument of functions, but I had the same incorrect result.

"c_list" is consisted a tuples with second "None's" followed by a next nesting level list.

P.S. Sorry, outdated browser was spoiling my code indenting. Fixed.

Comment: Fix your indenting first in the posted code.

Comment: What is the format of `c_list`?

Comment: I'm confused by what result you want.